# Is 会不会 in 你会不会修我的电脑 okay?

Tags: grammar

Please, is this sentence grammatically correct?

> A:请问，**你会不会修我的电脑**
> B :对不起，我不会修电脑

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give context, this sentence can have two meanings.
when 会 used as an auxiliary verb(such as in your sentence), it has two main functions: indicating ability or willingness.

so when you say: "你会不会修我的电脑", it  can have two different meanings, one is "are you willing to repair my computer"  another is "do you have the ability to repair my computer"

so, without preceding text, your sentence contains a certain ambiguity.

Comment: What is the meaning of "willing"? I think you want to say "willing and able (能夠)". Also "Ability" means 能力, the reply to your question will be either "能" or "不能", which differs from the OP's stated answer - "不会".

Comment: l check the question again, you are right, in that case, 会 means "how-to".however,会 doesn't always mean ”how-to", see a short conversation：ask:来世你还会跟我在一起吗 answer:不，我不会. In this situation, 会  express your wish

Comment: I feel that in your example willingness is just an implied extension from the use of "会“ as a future tense marker. I would translate your short conversation as: Will you still be with me in the world to come? Answer: No, I will not.

Comment: @BuddyL yes,make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This usage is right.
"会" can be translated to "can"/"be able to".
"X不X" can be translated to "whether A or not"
So "会不会" is "whether someone can or can not do something"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is correct.

会不会 is the short form of query - 会(know-how), 還是不会(or don't know-how)? The anticipated answer is either 会 or 不会.

The English equivalent is "Do you know how to...?"

Comment: 会不会 is not equivalent to  "Do you know how to...?" exactly, see my answer below, you cannot sum up in a word

Comment: IMHO, "Do you know how to... or not" is better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can repair computers.

你会不会修我的电脑吗？
Can you fix my computer?
对不起，我不会修电脑。
Sorry, I can't fix computers.

你会修电脑吗？
Can you fix computers?
对不起，我不会修电脑。
Sorry, I can't fix computers.

I know you can fix computers.

你能帮我修一下电脑吗？
Could you help me to fix this / a computer?
可以啊！
Sure!